# Image color conversation in compositor for AgX

Tags: compositing-nodes, color, color-management

I used to use color convention for Filmic like this:

[image]

But it doesn't work with AgX:

[image]

Convert color space doesn't work correctly even with filmic:

[image]

That am I doing wrong? That is the proper way to get image match colors in AgX color transform?

Comment: The “most close” approach would be to convert a “colour space” as you did in the third result, but even then it will likely yield less than optimal results. You can try setting the input to AgX Base and see if it gets closer.